# can not run Jupyter sucessfully

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CIMQ.png)

Hello team, I want to run Jupyter on CMD but the browser does not show up anything, below picture for your reference. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the image attached, seems that there are no problem with your jupyter instances.

My Tips is to install the `jupyter-lab` instead of (the old) `jupyter notebook`.

Jupyter can be accessed by the browser, so you have to open your favorite browser and navigate to the url that is print in the console.

Note, you have to copy the token too in order to access to Jupyter, in other case, you can use the following command:

```bsh
jupyter notebook --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```

Note: this is a security breach, cause everyone that have access to your network can execute python/shell script from Jupyter, cause it is accessibile for everyone without password.